# Is there a Slide Image Gallery for Xamarin Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am looking for a image gallery to use on Xamarin Android for a app i am creating but cant cant find any Gallery that slides left or right, Cant even find any blogs post on creating it to

I found a this one for Android its Called Android Image Slider

```
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider
```

But I cant open it Xamarin Studio

Also I am using the free version of Xamarin Studio

Is there any way i can achieve this using Xamarin?

Comment: You can use ViewPager: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39918404/xamarin-android-how-do-i-create-a-swipeable-image-gallery-using-viewpager

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a image slider in xamarin android using FragmentStatePager adapter. You need three things 
1) Main Activity which implements Adapter (Point #2)

2) Implementation of FragmentStatePagerAdapter for items and instantiate the fragment class (Point#3).

3) You need to implement fragment and set the image on the view. This fragment is then instantiated from the FragmentStatePagerAdapter and displayed on the screen as you scroll.

All you have to do count the no.of images you have in library and then on the activity, you need to shift the images on the view pager at certain time interval.

```
    //displaying image for 2 seconds
    Thread.Sleep (2000);
    //Updating the view pager with the next image.
    this.RunOnUiThread (() => _pager.SetCurrentItem (imageValue, true));
```

SetCurrentItem method on viewpager will show the display of the fragment.

Full Example and explanation in detail is available on Code Project 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1038358/Xamarin-Android-Image-Auto-Slider-and-OOM-Issue-Ha

Source code can be downloaded from my GIT HUB.
https://github.com/sahilkhan99/learnings/tree/master/autoImageSlider

Cheers