# Xamarin.Android How do I create a swipeable image gallery using ViewPager?

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-viewpager, xamarin.android

Android gallery is now deprecated, so I need to use ViewPager. I only found code samples for Xamarin.Forms, so I would appreciate if someone could help me with a code sample for Xamarin.Android.

My question is different from [Click on Viewpager Xamarin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209015/click-on-viewpager-xamarin-android) because I don't need to click the photos, I only needed to swipe the images in the gallery.

Comment: There are so many tutorials to show you how to make native viewpages in xamarin.android. That are really comprehensive. Google for some.

Comment: If any of that would have worked for what I need, I wouldn't have posted the question.

Comment: Have you looked at Cheesebarons working sample on his git repo? https://github.com/Cheesebaron/ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: I'm in the same boat right now.  All the tutorials I've found so far are either too basic for what I need or so complicated I can't really even begin to use them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click on Viewpager Xamarin Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209015/click-on-viewpager-xamarin-android)

Comment: I edited how the question is different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although its a different question there is a solution here that doesn't require you to use an image fragment for a simple slider.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33209130/5436000

```
public class ImageSliderAdapter : PagerAdapter
{
    Context _context;
    List<string> _imageUrls;

    public ImageSliderAdapter (Context context, List<string> imageUrls)
    {
        _imageUrls = imageUrls;
        _context = context;
    }

    public override bool IsViewFromObject (Android.Views.View view, Java.Lang.Object @object)
    {
        return view == ((LinearLayout)@object);
    }

    public override int Count {
        get {
            return _imageUrls.Count;
        }
    }

    public override void DestroyItem (ViewGroup container, int position, Java.Lang.Object objectValue)
    {
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem (ViewGroup container, int position)
    {

        View view = container;
        var inflater = _context.GetSystemService (Context.LayoutInflaterService) as LayoutInflater;
        view = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.image_slider_item, null);
        var child = view.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.image_slider_item);
        child.Click += (o, e) =>
        {
            //your code here
        };

        Bitmap image = null;
        Task.Run (() => {
            URL url = new URL (_imageUrls [position]);
            image = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream (url.OpenConnection ().InputStream);
        }).ContinueWith (t => {
            (_context as MainView).RunOnUiThread (() => {
                child.SetImageBitmap (image);
            });
        });

        container.AddView (view);
        return view;
    }
}
```