# How to implement image swiping in xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am a beginner in xamarin android,I want to implement image swiping in my page.How can  I do this?

Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ViewPager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/view-pager/).

You need use [PagerAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/view-pager/viewpager-and-views#create-the-adapter) to display your images.

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39918404/xamarin-android-how-do-i-create-a-swipeable-image-gallery-using-viewpager) is about how to use it with image.

Comment: Almost, actually I want the swiping events such as (left,right,bottom,top) and also do some operations on the event triggers.